# Encoding issues with regards to non-alphabet characters

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption

I am trying to create an encode function that will take an input such as "Hello!" and produce an encrypted response such as "8.5.12.12.15.999".  I am struggling with the non-alphabet items such as when I input an exclamation point, i am receiving an error due to my inability to use the '.lower' method.  I am also having trouble with replacing the non-alphabet character with "999". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import string

def encode(saying):
    saying = saying.lower()
    if type(saying) != str:
        return print("Enter a string")
    else:
        Dict = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase,range(1,27)))
        encode_list = []
        for item in saying:
            encode_list.append(Dict[item])
        output = ".".join(map(str,encode_list))
        return print(output)
    encode("Hello")
```

Comment: Have a look at ROT-47 as an idea to cover the printable ASCII characters from ! to ~.  You could extend the range of characters covered by your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple check in the start i.e `isalpha()` or `isdigit()` during input to check if the characters of the string have any special characters (any character which is not an alphabet or digit will be a special character). Once its found replace that with 999 in the new string(you can't replace it in the same string as strings are immutable in python)

You could also `import re` and define a set of special characters i.e `regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')` and check for special characters using `regex.search(string_name)` however that's not recommended as there may be some edge cases.